# Trying to refactor my listener callback for google maps in backbone.js app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to refactor a google.maps.event.addListener call's anonymous function. Here is what I originally have, which works perfectly fine. Note: The initialize function is run through a loop in some other view, which creates these Truck views. Remember, this code works perfectly and manages to loop through all my markers and set the event listener accordingly.

```
FoodTruckFinder.Views.TruckView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(options) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: options['map'],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        optimized: false, //stops marker from flashing
        position: options['foodPos']//LatLng
      }); 

      var infoWindow = options['infoWindow'];
      var self = this;

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

        // bounce once
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        marker.setAnimation(null);

        var content = '<div><strong>'+this.model.get('applicant')+
                      '</strong><p>'+this.model.get('address')+
                      '</p><p>'+this.model.get('fooditems')+'</p></div>';

        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
      });

    }

  })
```

This is the refactored code, which doesn't seem to work. My goal was to place the anonymous function into some other chunk of code because that would make it more readable.

```
FoodTruckFinder.Views.TruckView = Backbone.View.extend({

 initialize: function(options) {

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: options['map'],
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      optimized: false, //stops marker from flashing
      position: options['foodPos']//LatLng
    }); 

    this.infoWindow = options['infoWindow'];

    var populateMarkers = this.populateMarkers.bind(this); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', populateMarkers);

  },

  populateMarkers: function() {

    this.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    this.marker.setAnimation(null);

    var content = '<div><strong>'+this.model.get('applicant')+
                     '</strong><p>'+this.model.get('address')+
                     '</p><p>'+this.model.get('fooditems')+'</p></div>';

    this.infoWindow.setContent(content);
    this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
  }

})
```

This doesn't work. What happens is only one marker ends up showing up on the map (even though I should have many) and the callback doesn't do what it is supposed to with the infoWindow. In short, it doesn't work.

I was wondering if someone more experienced could see a big flaw in why this doesn't work.

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but are you actually sure the initialize is being run as a constructor? Because if not, 'this' will be bound to the window, and you might end up running lots of instances of populateMarkers() against a single value of options[foodPos]. Perhaps you could check if there really is just a single truck, or actually lots of trucks in exactly the same spot? Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is your problem, but you are not using the scope correctly.
You are assigning `var self = this` but never use it in your anon function.

```
var content = '<div><strong>' + self.model.get('applicant') +
              '</strong><p>' + self.model.get('address') + 
              '</p><p>' + self.model.get('fooditems')+'</p></div>';
```

Also, consider using a template engine to prevent XSS, and to gain more maintainability:

```
var tempalte = _.template([
  '<div>',
    '<strong><%- applicant %></strong>',
    '<p><%- address %></p>',
    '<strong><%- fooditems %></strong>',
  '</div>'
].join(''));

var content = template(self.model.toJSON());
```

Comment: The self aliasing is done in the original code, which the OP has refactored. He's now managing the value of this by calling function.prototype.bind on populateMarkers.

Comment: which, BTW, will not work on legacy browsers. TO be honest, I can't see how it ever worked.

Comment: if he was testing it in IE8, he'd get an exception (though yes, it is problematic for production code). It looks as though the code is running, but not working as expected. I don't know a lot about backbone, but I suspect the issue is that `this` is being shared amongst all renders of the truck on the map.